# rest_framework.request.WrappedAttributeError: 'AccountManager' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am working on my Django project, I am getting this error but i don't really know how to fix it exactly, i have created my custom user model and the user manager

```
class AccountManager(BaseManager):
def create_user(self, email, fullname=None, birthday=None,zipcode=None, password=None):
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
    user = self.model(Email_Address=self.normalize_email(email),
    name=self.normalize_email(email),
    Date_of_Birth=birthday,
    zipcode=zipcode
    )
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using='self._db')
    return user

def create_superuser(self, Email_Address, username, password):
    user=self.create_user(Email_Address=self.normalize_email(Email_Address), password=password,)
    user.is_admin = True
    user.is_active = True
    user.is_staff = True
    user.is_superuser = True
    user.save(using='self._db')




class User(AbstractUser):
Email_Address = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
Date_of_Birth = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
username= models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
USERNAME_FIELD = 'Email_Address'
objects = AccountManager()
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']


def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

because i am using rest_framework_simplejwt for authentication i am getting this error when i try to log in

```
user = self.user_model.objects.get(**{api_settings.USER_ID_FIELD: user_id})
rest_framework.request.WrappedAttributeError: 'AccountManager' object has no attribute 'get'
```

can anyone please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

According to this section, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-a-manager-for-a-custom-user-model, you need to extend your custom user manager from `BaseUserManager`.

In your code you extended from the `BaseManager`.